# Fastest Way To Populate Drop Down Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just taken over a project using `webforms` and `C#` with my `asp.net` project.  My page load times are very slow and I assume it is due to the multiple database calls that are being made, however I am not sure how to do it any differently.  For example, I have one page that holds 3 different `dropdownlists` each `dropdownlist` is populated in the `Page_Load()` event handler, but all 3 have there own database call.

Below is pseducode to show the approach being used.  What is the proper way to accomplish something like this?

```
namespace CEDS
{
public partial class BBLL : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private C2 _C2 = new C2();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetDataForDropDown1();
            GetDataForDropDown2();
            GetDataForDropDown3();
        }
    }
    private void GetDataForDropDown1()
    {   
        DS = _C2.GetDataForDropDown1();
        this.gv1.DataSource = DS;
        this.gv1.DataBind();  
        this.gv1.Visible = true;            
    }
    private void GetDataForDropDown2()
    {   
        DS = _C2.GetDataForDropDown2();
        this.gv2.DataSource = DS;
        this.gv2.DataBind(); 
        this.gv2.Visible = true;            
    }
    private void GetDataForDropDown3()
    {   
        DS = _C2.GetDataForDropDown3();
        this.gv3.DataSource = DS;
        this.gv3.DataBind(); 
        this.gv3.Visible = true;            
    }

}
public class C2
{
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private DatabaseAccessLayer DAL = new DatabaseAccessLayer();

    public DataSet GetDataForDropDown1()
    {
        DS = new DataSet(); 
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.RunStoredProcedure1 ");
        DS = DAL.ExecuteSqlQuery(databaseConnection, DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
        return DS;
    }
    public DataSet GetDataForDropDown2()
    {
        DS = new DataSet(); 
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.RunStoredProcedure2 ");
        DS = DAL.ExecuteSqlQuery(databaseConnection, DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
        return DS;
    }
    public DataSet GetDataForDropDown3()
    {
        DS = new DataSet(); 
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.Append("exec dbo.RunStoredProcedure3 ");
        DS = DAL.ExecuteSqlQuery(databaseConnection, DAL.SqlQueryBuilder.ToString());
        return DS;
    }
}
public class DatabaseAccessLayer
{
    public DataSet ExecuteSqlQuery(string connectionString, string sqlQuery)
    {
        try
        {            
            _connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString].ToString();       
            _sqlDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _sqlDatabaseConnection);
            _sqlDatabaseConnection.Open();
            _sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;   
            _dataSet = new DataSet();
            _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqlCommand);            
            _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet, "Data");
            return _dataSet;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
        finally
        {
            _sqlDatabaseConnection.Close();
            _sqlCommand.Dispose();
            _sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should turn on SQL Profiler and load the page, then isolate each SqlQuery and copy/paste those into SSMS.  The query execution time will let you see how much time is spent on those queries as opposed to inside .Net (although there are some exceptions to this rule).  If you also turn on Execution Plan it will warn if indexes are missing on the data.

Comment: How do I turn on SQL Profiler?

Comment: I just noticed you have SqlQuery *and* a stored procedure.  What are each doing?

Comment: SQL Profiler is a separate tool that can be installed with SQL Server.  If you don't have it you'll have to try writing the SQL code to run the procedures in SSMS directly, e.g. `exec myproc @param1=foo, @param2=bar`

Comment: Can you update your code with a (brief) example, just so I know you're not creating procedures in ASP.NET which would be awful?!

Comment: @EvilDr - just threw together the meat and potatos of how things are executed.  I may have omitted a few variable assignments, but it should get the point across.

Comment: I don't see why you need to create a SQL query *and* run a procedure, when the procedure could do both.  You should try the profiler to capture all the SQL then run it all in SMSS and check the execution time.

Comment: @EvilDr - you are correct, I commented out the SQL Query lines and whilst it still is slow everything loads as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Page_Load()
{
  var t1 = GetDataForDropDown1();
  var t2 = GetDataForDropDown2();
  var t3 = GetDataForDropDown3();
  await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
  PopulateDD1();
  PopulateDD2();
  PopulateDD3();
}
async Task GetDataForDropDown1()
{
  SqlQuery
  Call To Database Access Layer
  await Execute Stored Procedure
  Store Returned Result In Dataset  
}
async Task GetDataForDropDown2()
{
  SqlQuery
  Call To Database Access Layer
  await Execute Stored Procedure
  Store Returned Result In Dataset  
}
async Task GetDataForDropDown3()
{
  SqlQuery
  Call To Database Access Layer
  await Execute Stored Procedure
  Store Returned Result In Dataset  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
Parallel.Invoke(GetDataForDropDown1, GetDataForDropDown2, GetDataForDropDown3);
```

So at least you aren't waiting for the first to complete until you start waiting for the second and third.

It might be more effective to have a single stored procedure that returns *all three* recordsets, so your database connection and retrieval roundtrip is only made *once*. But that will probably mean you have to change your data layer code.

Comment: Just out of interest, if the lists are nested, so the first must load its values before the second one starts loading, does this approach still work?

Answer (score 1):

The better approach might be this, try it.

```
Page_Load()
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     LoadData();
   }
}

LoadData()
{
// PopulateDropDown1 Code
// PopulateDropDown2 Code
// PopulateDropDown3 Code
}
```

`if(!Page.IsPostBack)` prevents `LoadData()` to call on every postback.